# Firebase sign in error with Firebase UI Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tyVdohSf4d4&c=z221y1thaz2tjf4lbacdp4315wd4hhkwn0uuht4avhpw03c010c).
It should go to HomeActivity but it's not: it shows MainActivity instead.
I am new to coding and don't know what to do.

I already added SHA-1 to Firebase.

```
E/AuthUI: A sign-in error occurred.
    com.firebase.ui.auth.FirebaseUiException: Error when saving credential.
        at com.firebase.ui.auth.viewmodel.smartlock.SmartLockHandler$1.onComplete(SmartLockHandler.java:98)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 16: No eligible accounts can be found.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zai.zaf(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zaj.onComplete(Unknown Source:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.zaa(Unknown Source:172)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BasePendingResult.setResult(Unknown Source:131)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BaseImplementation$ApiMethodImpl.setResult(Unknown Source:36)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzo.zzc(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzv.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zzd.onTransact(Unknown Source:12)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:731)
```

Comment: Please consider adding the code you are using, it puts things in a contexts and you'll be more likely to get help.

Comment: Please add the code and indicate the exact line at which this error occurs and also please responde with @AlexMamo